# Convert date with GMT php

Tags: php, time

I get date in this format: `2016-09-23T19:15:00+02:00`.

How can I with php get format: `2016-09-23 21:15`.

I tried:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('2016-09-23T19:15:00+02:00');
```

But i get

```
2016-09-23 19:15.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
function parseDate($date){
    $parts = explode("+", $date);
    if(isset($parts[1])) {
        $ph = (int)explode(":", $parts[1])[0];
        // take "02:00", extract "02" and convert to int. result: 2
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($parts[0]." + $ph hour"));
    }
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
}

echo parseDate("2016-09-23T19:15:00+02:00");
// output 2016-09-23 21:15:00
echo parseDate("2016-09-23T19:15:00");
// output 2016-09-23 19:15:00
```

You can check it on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/IfqHO)

***Note***: this avoids using `date_default_timezone_set()` which sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions. If your application is already setting a default timezone, overriding it for a simple parsing is not really recommended.